# Pyinstaller not installing

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I had Pyinstaller earlier but this morning i deleted it by mistake now it isn't reinstalling here are some pictures [start like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXip9.png)

[start giving errors] [2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKfCV.jpg)
[and end up like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjSl5.jpg)

please help i'm a windows 7 user

Comment: Try running the installer as administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
python -m pip uninstall PyInstaller

python -m pip install PyInstaller
```

Comment: did you test?If you tested the post if it worked, if it didn't, describe what the output was. return the same output?

Comment: I have tested I will send screenshot Tom as it is night

Comment: It has been an year but it was that my anti virus was blocking run.exe and rund_d.exe as it detected them as trojan it got fixed in next version